# Compare the last element in Rails active record

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two models Student and StudentRecord. Student Record has start_date, end_date and class_course_id among its attributes and it belongs to Student

```
scope = Student.eager_load(:student_record)
```

Now, I want to get the students whose latest(according to start_date) student_record's class_course_id is the same as a given class_course_id. something like:

```
scope = scope.where("student_records.order(start_date asc).last.class_course_id = ?", params[:class_course_id])
```

Obviously, the above statement is not correct but I hope it describes what I would like to get.

Answer (score 0):

The below should do

```
Student.eager_load(:student_record).where("student_records.class_course_id = ?", params[:class_course_id]).order('student_records.start_date asc').last
```

Comment: No, this does not work. I think it orders it after it already fetched a match.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Order by` clause and descend to get the latest dates `.order("student_records.start_date DESC")` and in the `where` clause, the records will be filtered out `.where("student_records.class_course_id = ?", params[:class_course_id])`. The `where` will come first then, the `order by desc` will sort it correctly.

```
scope.where("student_records.class_course_id = ?", params[:class_course_id]).order("student_records.start_date DESC")
```

And you can do `.limit(5)` to get the first 5 records that are the latest start_dates.

Comment: This does not get the desired results. Records that have matches which are not the last record are also being fetched

Comment: So use `.limit(1)` `scope.where("student_records.class_course_id = ?", params[:class_course_id]).order("student_records.start_date DESC").limit(1)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want all students, then this is a bit non-trivial in active record.

Identifying the last Student Record sounds like an important thing that would benefit from a scope:

```
def self.latest_for_student
  where("not exists (select null from student_records sr2 where sr2.student_id = student_records.student_id and sr2.start_date > student_records.start_date)")
end
```

... which means "return rows for which there does not exist another row in student_records for the same student_id, and a greater start_date"

Or...

```
def self.latest_for_student
  where("student_records.start_date = (select max(start_date) from student_records sr2 where sr2.student_id = student_records.student_id)")
end
```

... which means "return rows for which the start date is equal to the maximum start date for that student id"

Then you can:

```
class Student
  has_one :last_student_record, -> {merge(StudentRecord.latest_for_student)}, :class_name => "StudentRecord"
  has_one :last_class_course, :through => :last_student_record, :source => :class_course
end

class ClassCourse
  has_many :last_records_for_student, -> {merge(StudentRecord.latest_for_student)}, :class_name => "StudentRecord"
  has_many :students_having_as_last_course, :through => : last_records_for_student, :source => :student
end
```

Then you should be able to:

```
@course.students_having_as_last_course
```

Bit complex ... could be syntax errors ... let me know if there are.

Comment: Still trying to figure out your solution :-)